# C# MongoDB insert new object to List

Tags: c#, mongodb, list

I'm new to both C# and MongoDB. I'm trying to add a new object to a list in a MongoDB collection, here is my code:

**ProjectModel:**

```
class ProjectModel
{
    [BsonId]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public PartModel[] Parts { get; set; }
}
```

**PartModel:**

```
class PartModel
{
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public string PartName { get; set; }
}
```

**Method Class**

```
class MongoCRUD
{
    private IMongoDatabase db;
    
    public MongoCRUD(string database)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient();
        db = client.GetDatabase(database);
    }

    public void InsertPart<T>(string table,  Guid id, PartModel newPart)
    {       
        var collection = db.GetCollection<T>(table);
        var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("Id", id);          
        var update = Builders<ProjectModel>.Update.Push<PartModel>(e => e.Parts, newPart);
    }
}
```

**Main Class:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MongoCRUD db = new MongoCRUD("PartsManagerDB");

        PartModel newPart = new PartModel()
        {
            PartName = "Lower Bracket",
            PartNumber = "4000"

        };

        db.InsertPart<PartModel>("Projects", new Guid("f3784ba4-c422-43e0-80fd-41bb87b20f10"), newPart);
    }
}
```

The project 93100 is already in my db, but after executing my code, no error comes up but the collection is not being updated as you can see below:

[image: Snapshot from MongoDB Compass]

Comment: I think the `T` should be a `ProjectModel` not ``PartModel`` when calling the method `db.InsertPart`

Comment: Maybe go through the update functionality one more time https://developer.mongodb.com/quickstart/csharp-crud-tutorial

Comment: @Sajid tried but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the line that actually executes the two things you already have, `filter` and `update`.

```
public void InsertPart<T>(string table,  Guid id, PartModel newPart)
{       
    var collection = db.GetCollection<T>(table);
    var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("Id", id);          
    var update = Builders<ProjectModel>.Update.Push<PartModel>(e => e.Parts, newPart);

    // This line will actually update your DB with the new value.
    collection.FindOneAndUpdate<T>(filter, update);
}
```

[Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) on `FindOneAndUpdate()` method.

**Also**, in your Main() method, you need to use the class, `ProjectModel` instead of `PartModel` when calling the `InsertPart` method.

```
db.InsertPart<**ProjectModel**>("Projects", new Guid("f3784ba4-c422-43e0-80fd-41bb87b20f10"), newPart);
```

In the `InsertPart` method, `T` is used in your `filter`'s Builder and it should be ProjectModel to get the Project that you are updating... not Part. Part is being inserted to the `ProjectModel`'s `PartModel` array so the `T` should be `ProjectModel`.